# How to get current EF version

Tags: c#

Since new Entity Framework version I got from nuget broke some of my tests, in one of my projects I want to make sure the Entity Framework version installed as reference for the entire solution is the version 4.1.10331.0

What's the best way to find out I'm referencing entity framework 4.1.10331.0 since nuget installs it per solution? Reading packages.config? Going through all the assemblies in current domain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377821/entity-framework-how-can-i-tell-what-version-i-am-using

Comment: What do you see if you find the references files in the project, right click, properties and check the version numbers in there?

Comment: If I go and install version 4.1.10715.0 dll reference  is the same version and runtime version

Comment: This article can help you (EF Version History):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574253

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up getting the assembly version since I didn't find another way.