# How can i retrieve the version of Entity Framework in a WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get current EF version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315127/how-to-get-current-ef-version)

In my windows forms application, I want to display the Entity Framework version being used by the applications .edmx files. Is it possible to get the Entity Framework version from the app.config file or the .edmx file in C#?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("System.Data.Entity.dll");
Version ver = assembly.GetName().Version;
```

Comment: will the Assembly path be resolved when the application has been deployed to the client machine?

Answer (score 1):

The EDMX file version isn't related to Entity Framework version, although there's a version. Probably best is to simply check the version of `EntityFramework.dll` (assuming you're using more or less current version(s)) that's loaded in your application. I.e. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies` might be helpful.