# Entity Framework Version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, nuget

I am using VS 2013 for application development , I am not sure what version of Entity framework its being used in my project. Is there any way to find out current version of EF using package manager console ?

Comment: This old SO question might be helpful if it is not yet deprecated:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377821/entity-framework-how-can-i-tell-what-version-i-am-using

Comment: Put this command in the console Get-Package OR this one Find-Package [Id] [-Source <string>] [-First <int>] [-Skip <int>] [-AllVersions] [-IncludePrerelease] [-ExactMatch]

Answer (score 0):

You could run the `Get-Package` command targeting the `EntityFramework` package in the Package Manager Console:

```
Get-Package EntityFramework
```

After running the command, you'll see any instances within your solution (or selected scope) where Entity Framework is installed as seen below :

[image]