# Shorter delete query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code below a delete query using linq. But it feels like a long method?. Is there any alternative way to do this?.

```
var ListOfData = (from a in db.Table1 
                  join b in db.Table2 on a.Table1Id equals b.Table2Id  
                  where a.Table1Id == (param) select a)
                  .ToList();

foreach(var item in ListOfData )
{
    var DelRecord = (from a in db.Table1 
                     join b in db.Table2 on a.Table1Id equals b.Table2Id 
                     where a.Table1Id == item.TableId select a)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

    db.Table1.DeleteObject(DelRecord);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Why do you not have proper entities created? if they are joinable, you may as well just create a link in the Entity object, so you can reference Table1.table2.whatever.

Comment: Do you need to save your changes every iteration?

Comment: Shouldn't it be [ported] on Code Review SE forum?

Comment: You could use `RemoveRange` instead of  `DeleteObject`

Comment: Also, what is the point of DelRecord? Can't you just delete 'item' every iteration?

Comment: Is RemoveRange  native EF?

Comment: Never understood why some people insist on using `join` rather than _navigation properties_ that are already provided in EF.   Seems to defeat the purpose of an OO data structure in an ORM environment.   _[Don't use LINQ's `join`. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)_

Comment: Sorry all I got slow connection right now. @BlueBoy I can saveChanges after all iteration right?.

Comment: @TriV `RemoveRange`?. Its my first time to hear that one.. Maybe I'll study that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the second query, you already have the data you need.

```
var ListOfData = (from a in db.Table1 
                  join b in db.Table2 on a.Table1Id equals b.Table2Id 
                  where a.Table1Id == (param) select a)
                  .ToList();

foreach(var item in ListOfData )
{
    db.Table1.DeleteObject(item);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

If you're using Entity Framework 6, they have introduced `RemoveRange()` method.

```
var ListOfData = (from a in db.Table1 
                  join b in db.Table2 on a.Table1Id equals b.Table2Id 
                  where a.Table1Id == (param) select a)
                  .ToList();

db.Table1.RemoveRange(ListOfData);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Its still the same to mine right?.. And uses a long code

Comment: Good spot about EF6.  Apparently _"[Note that if AutoDetectChangesEnabled is set to true (which is the default), then DetectChanges will be called once before delete any entities and will not be called again. This means that in some situations **RemoveRange may perform significantly better than calling Remove** multiple times would do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange(v=vs.113).aspx)"_.  Nice!  +1

Comment: I don't have the `RemoveRange`. How to check what EF that I am using?.

Comment: Should be written in your App.config or Web.config, or check your packages list, or open NuGet and seach for EntityFramework

Comment: Its okay now thanks to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377821/determine-version-of-entity-framework-i-am-using) by ChrisS